Swift Closure Capture List without the "in" keyword
does anybody know where this is documented? All the places I searched for, closures require a in keyword after the capture list but there is a valid case in which you can just specify the capture list. I guess this is the default behaviour of the closure made explicit.
var greeting = "Hello, playground"

let closure = { [greeting]
     print(greeting) 
}


The in keyword is required if you want to have a capture list. Don't ignore the compiler warnings!
warning: expression of type '[String]' is unused
let closure = { [greeting]
                ^~~~~~~~~~

It's telling you that this [greeting] is being understood as a [String] (i.e. Array<String>). So this is a single-element array literal that's being unused, as if you had written:
let closure = {
    [greeting] // Unused Array!
    print(greeting)
}

You need the in so that this syntax is treated as a capture list, instead.

I am using a playground and I get no warning for not using the in keyword and actually it makes a difference if I add it vs if I do not. Without the in keyword if I change the variable before calling the closure it will also reflect the change in the message that is being printed. If I do add the in then the closure is making a copy of the variable and changing the variable before calling the block prints the initial value of the variable.

Compiler warnings are disabled in playgrounds?! (that's madness...) And yes, what you're describing makes sense. [greeting] in ... is declaring a capture list that does an immutable capture of (the value of) greeting, which behaves as if the value was copied. Without the in, the [greeting] is no longer a capture list, so the closure just ends up with a normal implicit capture of the greeting variable, which can observe changes made to that variable.

@AlexStanciu Without using in, greeting is not captured. If you want greeting to be captured then you must use in along with [greeting]. If you have no need to capture greeting then you don't need in and of course you shouldn't add [greeting].

@HangarRash Not quite. greeting is captured in both cases, but they're different kinds of capture. [greeting] in is a by-value immutable capture of the value of the greeting variable at the time the closure is being created. Without it, there's still an implicit capture of the greeting variable itself.

@HangarRash my question is why does it work? it shouldn't or it should give me a warning or an error. Is this a language feature or a bug?

@AlexStanciu Does my explanation make sense? What part of it seems like it could be a bug?

@Alexander it does make sense but in your example above you got a weird warning that misidentified the captured variable as an array. In the playground has no problem running the code without any warning and it works as intended.

Because playgrounds don't show warnings. The fault is with you for testing in a playground.

oh, nevermind, indeed in the playground it is still recognised as an array but without warnings.
